v-menu anchored in wrong place
I'm using vue3 on VS Studio with a standard project setup.
Default.vue
<template>
  <v-app>
    <default-bar />
    <default-view />
  </v-app>
</template>

<script setup>
import DefaultBar from './AppBar.vue'
import DefaultView from './View.vue'
</script>

AppBar
<!-- Relevent Part -->
<v-menu location-strategy="connected" location="end bottom">
        <template #activator="{ props }">
          <v-btn v-bind="props" v-show="!auth.isAuthenticated">Sign Up</v-btn>
          <v-btn v-bind="props" icon v-show="auth.isAuthenticated">
            <v-icon>mdi-account</v-icon>
          </v-btn>
        </template>
        <v-card>
          <v-container>
            <v-row v-show="!auth.isAuthenticated" class="align-center">
              <v-col>
                <v-btn to="/auth">Sign Up Now!</v-btn>
              </v-col>
            </v-row>
            <v-row v-show="auth.isAuthenticated" class="align-center">
              <v-col>
                <v-avatar>J</v-avatar>
              </v-col>
              <v-col>
                <v-row>
                  <v-col>Jamie Marshall</v-col>
                </v-row>
                <v-row>
                  <v-col>{{ auth.getEmail }}</v-col>
                </v-row>
              </v-col>
            </v-row>
          </v-container>
          <v-card-actions v-show="auth.isAuthenticated">
            <v-btn color="error" @click="signOut">Sign Out</v-btn>
            <v-spacer></v-spacer>
            <v-btn color="warning" to="/profile">Edit Profile</v-btn>
          </v-card-actions>
        </v-card>
      </v-menu>

Weird Result:


In the first image the v-menu overlay renders in the wrong place, and in the second image it renders in the correct place.  Given the vueity in the source this should not be the case. Here are the interpreted overlays:
<!--Bad Render-->
<div class="v-overlay v-overlay--absolute v-overlay--active v-theme--light v-locale--is-ltr v-menu" data-v-3d872d92="" style="z-index: 2000;">
  <!---->
  <div class="v-overlay__content" style="max-height: 1247px; max-width: 1942px; min-width: 0px; --v-overlay-anchor-origin: bottom left; transform-origin: left top; top: 12px; left: 12px;">
    <div data-v-3d872d92="" class="v-card v-theme--light v-card--density-default v-card--variant-elevated">

<!--Good Render-->
<div class="v-overlay__content" style="max-height: 1247px; max-width: 1942px; min-width: 48px; --v-overlay-anchor-origin: bottom right; transform-origin: right top; top: 48px; left: 1673px;">
  <div data-v-3d872d92="" class="v-card v-theme--light v-card--density-default v-card--variant-elevated">
    <!---->
    <div class="v-card__loader">

Notice this part in each rendered output:
--v-overlay-anchor-origin: bottom left; transform-origin: left top;
--v-overlay-anchor-origin: bottom right; transform-origin: right top;

Not sure what is causing this rendering difference.  I've seen another SO post claim resolved due to not wrapping the application in , but that is clearly done here.

My guess is VMenu fails to resolve the activator or content element? Hard to say without seeing it in action, consider creating a playground.
